# Would like to know SQL Azure available space from ASP.Net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-sql-database

I am doing smoke test of my web application and in that I am required to check free database space out of total space to display alert on smoke test page. I am connected to Sql Azure database. How can i do this, anyone can suggest me here to implement this smoke test??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan Dunns's Blog has a entry on [Calculating The Size Of Your SQL Azure Database](http://dunnry.com/blog/2010/03/05/CalculatingTheSizeOfYourSQLAzureDatabase.aspx)
namely:

```
select
  sum(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024
from
  sys.dm_db_partition_stats
GO

select
  sys.objects.name, sum(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024
from
  sys.dm_db_partition_stats, sys.objects
where
  sys.dm_db_partition_stats.object_id = sys.objects.object_id
group by sys.objects.name
```

run the query and display it on your smoke test page - or run the query on a schedule and send out an alert as you approach your db max size.

Comment: Great, i got used space, can you give me query to get Total space so i can use both in my smoke test page.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, DATABASEPROPERTYEX('NAME OF YOUR DATABASE' , 'MaxSizeInBytes'))/1073741824.0  AS [MaxSizeInGB];

Comment: see http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/a-small-collection-of-sql-azure-queries/

Comment: Excellent, i just replaced db_name() in 'NAME OF YOUR DATABASE'and it's work nice, thanks a lot my friend!:)